# How to install MySQL 5.7.x on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos, upgrade, mysql-5.7

I need to obtain the functionality of **MySQL 5.7**. I had zend server 9 (first 9 version). After reinstallation of zend server (it doesn't supports upgrade).
- Result: MySQL 5.5 !

May there exist solutions for:

- Upgrade mysql inside zend framework?
- Install other apache2.4+mysql5.7+php7 developer server?
- some other solution.

Requirements:

- PHP7.0.8 or later
- MySQL 5.7
- Apache 2.4 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql.com offers a automatic dmg installer, which I find I have the most success with. It typically installs in /usr/local/mysql so you may want to try deleting any other installations you have on your system first.

You can download it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

As for apache and php I find that I typically stick with the ones preloaded into os x, you can There are a number of articles out there on how to active these, but I believe its just a matter of uncommenting the php LoadModule line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and then starting apache in terminal with the apachectl command.

Comment: Thx for answer. I will try to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall your existing version of `mysql` and install `mysql 5.7`

```
mysql.server stop       # kill the running process
brew uninstall mysql    # uninstall mysql
brew update             # update brew
brew install mysql@5.7  # install mysql 5.7
```

Now you can start `mysql.server` with `/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start`

---

Modify your `PATH` variable in `~/.bash_profile` so you can start it with just `mysql.server start`

```
# ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `https://dbngin.com/`

Then after that i went to `/usr/local`

Then I saw a folder name for each of the MySQL versions I had installed using dbngin

Then after that I added it to path. Then that was it.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/path-to-mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

You know, after MySQL is uninstalled and reinstalled via homebrew, it will prompt: 1. Upgrade to macOS 10.13; 2. Upgrade to Xcode 9.2.

If you don't want to upgrade the system or Xcode version, then request the MySQL official website to download:
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

The MySQL version suitable for macOS 10.12 ranges from 5.7.17 to 5.7.23.